# Installing TinyMCE on Django (And using it on forms)

Tags: django, tinymce, wysiwyg, django-tinymce

Hi Im trying to install TinyMCE on a Django project and Im totally lost about static files, MEDIA, and the world itself.
I want to use TinyMCE in one of the fields of a form:

```
class MovieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['title', 'language', 'description']
        widgets = {
            'languages': forms.SelectMultiple(),
            'description': TinyMCE({'cols':80, 'rows':30}),
        }
```

I installed django-tinymce
`pip install django-tinymce`

Then I added it to the installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
  'tinymce',
   ...
)
```

And then added the urls in my project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    ...
)
```

Great. So what do I do next? 
I read the Configuration part on http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration but I dont get it. 
Should I add `TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_URL, "path/to/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")` to my project `settings.py`? Where do I put `tiny_mce.js`?  Should I configure MEDIA_URL somewhere? 
Would be awesome if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this, so I'm posting an answer in case anyone else comes across this.

I read more in details the documentation on Static files (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/), and read the related section of the great book Tango with Django (http://www.tangowithdjango.com/).

That helped me to understand the MEDIA and STATIC setup I needed to get right in order to get working TinyMCE with Django. 
tiny_mce.js went to the static files folder (specifically to static/tiny_mce/).

The settings.py of Tinymce check if static is confidured, and points there to get the needed files. Tadaa! It works!
Hopefully it will help someone!